# How to use an extern union array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, extern, unions

I want to use a union array similar to that one `chux` suggested

```
union {
  uint8_t u8[12];
  uint16_t u16[6];
} *array_u;

array_u = calloc(1, sizeof *array_u);
assert(array_u);

printf("array_u->u8[0] = %" PRIu8 "\n", array_u->u8[0]);

array_u->u16[0] = 1234;
printf("array_u->u16[0] = %" PRIu16 "\n", array_u->u16[0]);
...
```

Source: [Is it okay to store different datatypes in same allocated memory in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549393/is-it-okay-to-store-different-datatypes-in-same-allocated-memory-in-c)

I want to use it as a global array that different files need to have access to it. So I tried `globals.h`:

```
extern union {
    uint8_t u8[12];
    uint16_t u16[6];
} *array_u;
```

And I want to allocate and free it in this file `memory.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "globals.h"

void allocate_array_u(void){
    array_u = calloc(1, sizeof *array_u);
}
```

Bud sadly I receive a `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol array_u`

How can I fix that?

**Solution:**
I forgot to define the union in `main.c` or `memory.c`:

```
array_u_t *array_u;
```

Comment: You named it `array` in `globals.h` but assigning to `array_u` in `memory.c`.

Comment: Sorry, wrong code in the question. I edited it. The problem still remains.

Comment: If the name is correct and you included the header (as in your post), I don't see why it wouldn't work. You still get the *same* error?

Comment: Yes, I don't get a warning inside the source code but receive the error during compiling.

Comment: What you get a linker error. How are you compiling the whole project? (where's main(), do you access `array_u` in main() and if so, do you include `globals.h`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to declaring `array_u` as `extern`, you also need to *define* the variable. `extern` just says to find the definition somewhere else. That definition needs to exist somewhere.

Try the following.

Change `globals.h` as follows:

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t u8[12];
    uint16_t u16[6];
} array_u_t;

extern array_u_t *array_u;
```

Define `array_u` in `memory.c` as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "globals.h"

array_u_t *array_u; // <---------------- definition

void allocate_array_u(void){
    array_u = calloc(1, sizeof *array_u);
}
```

Comment: Thats it. Just forgot about defining! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Suggest giving the union a 'tag' name.

```
union myunion 
{
    uint8_t u8[12];
    uint16_t u16[6];
};
```

Then on a separate statement declare an instance of a pointer to the union:

```
 union myunion *array_u = NULL;
```

then set the pointer to the union to a value:

```
array_u = calloc(1, sizeof union myunion);
```

Note: calling `assert()` will not tell the user what went wrong and is a poor choice in production code.

Instead, suggest:

```
if( NULL == array_u )
{ // then calloc failed
    perror( "calloc for instance of union myunion failed: );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, calloc successful
```

Note: placing the literal 'NULL' on the left, so a keystroke error, like typing `=` rather than `==` will be caught by the compiler rather than you spending hours and hours looking for that 'oops'.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `array_u` as an external symbol in every source file that includes `globals.h` but where it resides? Every variable must be defined somewhere; i.e. not declared as `external` and, optional, initialized.

Pick the most appropriate C file and write in it:

```
union {
    uint8_t u8[12];
    uint16_t u16[6];
} *array_u = NULL;
```

You better use `typedef` to get a name to the union type of variable `array_u` to avoid defining it twice.

Write in `globals.h`:

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t u8[12];
    uint16_t u16[6];
} array_u_type;
extern array_u_type *array_u;
```

Write in one of the C files (`memory.c`, for example):

```
#include "globals.h"

array_u_type *array_u = NULL;
```

Replace in the example above `array_u_type` with any name you like for the new data type.

Comment: I see that your comment came out right about the same time. My apologies. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @Ziffusion - not a problem. Reading both my and your answer carefully one can notice that while they both provide the same solution for the problem, they also provide different small hints here and there. Yours is more clear than mine, anyway ;-)